# Performance impact.. query running too long

Tags: sql, oracle11g, database-performance

I have written the below query but takes running too long.. how can i optimize this? can anyone have idea how to rewrite this logic with out using not exist logic?

```
SELECT s.sid
FROM book s
WHERE active    =1
AND (read_only IS NULL
OR read_only    = 0)
AND cdate      IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM contract con
  WHERE ((con.pid=s.sid)
  OR (con.bsid   =s.sid)
  OR (con.ssid   =s.sid)
  AND (con.cosid <5))
  )
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM pns WHERE staid=2 AND pns.abid=s.sid
  )
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM contract_ct WHERE contract_ct.cpid=s.sid
  )
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM cosa WHERE cosa.csid=s.sid
  );
```

Comment: Please include tables definition.

Comment: Book Table

sid        NUMBER [PRIMARY],
active     NUMBER,
read_only  NUMBER,
cdate      DATE,
lastupdatedon DATE,
state      NVARCHAR2,
country    NVARCHAR2

Comment: Please edit your question to include the DDL for your tables.  Tell us what indexes you have.  Show us the query plan you are getting.  Tell us how large the tables are and which predicates are going to be reasonably selective.  Quantify "too long".  Are we trying, for example, to take a query that runs in 50 ms and get it to run in 5 ms?  Or is the query running for hours and you want it to run in minutes?

Comment: @JustinCave Query running hours, i need to reduce as minutes.

Comment: There are lots of spurious parentheses in the first `not exists` clause - but not where they would be useful to ensure the `and`s and `or`s are combined correctly.

Comment: Please add the execution plan (which probably contains nested loops)

Comment: Justin cave and Tony this query only taking much time.. how can i rewrite this   AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM contract con
  WHERE ((con.pid=s.sid)
  OR (con.bsid   =s.sid)
  OR (con.ssid   =s.sid)
  AND (con.cosid <5))
  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got the brackets wrong.

```
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM contract con
  WHERE ((con.pid=s.sid)
  OR (con.bsid   =s.sid)
  OR (con.ssid   =s.sid)
  AND (con.cosid <5))
  )
```

Didn't you mean -

```
and not exists
    (
        select      1
        from        contract con
        where       (    con.pid  = s.sid
                      or con.bsid = s.sid
                      or con.ssid = s.sid
                    )
                and con.cosid < 5
    )
```

Comment: Noo.. how first condition will equal to second one??

Comment: @MuthusankarB, it won't, this was the point. So you did intend to `OR (con.ssid=s.sid AND con.cosid <5)?

Comment: in that single query we are checking 3 OR conditions where not exists of that table

Comment: @MuthusankarB, I didn't get what you are saying

Comment: how to rewrite the this line?                                                                                                                  AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM contract con
  WHERE ((con.pid=s.sid)
  OR (con.bsid   =s.sid)
  OR (con.ssid   =s.sid)
  AND (con.cosid <5))
  )

Comment: We don't necessarily need to rewrite it but I need to know if  `con.cosid <5` goes only with `con.ssid =s.sid` or it should be true for all other expressions. `(a or b or  (c and d))` or `(a or b or c) and d`

Comment: it show true for all the conditions, so that only prob

Comment: Markovtitz do u have any idea about this??

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you intention